# is there a way to use HTML to send an email via gmail

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

The tag `mailto:` in a link opens the default email client. However, many of the people I want to code for use GMail.

So, is there a way to craft an email and access the user's gmail tab so that the all she/he has to do is to click send?

Comment: No ... Just no. Or you'll have to tell all your users to define gmail as their default client but this is not a html problem anymore ...

Comment: If they have Gmail set as their default client, mailto: will open a compose message browser window.

Comment: if this was possible, there'd be far more sites out there trying to send spam by auto-populating your gmail with garbage... so, no.

Comment: In other words: This isn't something your code handles. It's something the end-user's computer configuration handles. Your job is to identify the link as an email address (which you've done). The rest is outside the scope of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the anchor like that:

```
<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@gmail.com&su=subject_here&body=body_here"></a>
```

Comment: And have all the **non**-gmail clients fail. Not a good idea.

Comment: Right. But **fiacobelli** asking about Gmail, so probably it's expected that Gmail accout exist. If no then user just see the Gmail's login page — not so awful :)

Comment: OK. Let's wait for questioner response. Any simple case has drawbacks and this one is VERY simple :)

Comment: So, yes. I can always add a radio button that asks whether they want to use Gmail or not. The only drawback of this answer is that it is a GET, which limits the size of the email. Otherwise this was exactly what I was looking for. It may help others a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid that there isn't such way. It's not something that you should be attempting to solve in your web application because user agents might behave differently. So just leave it that way.

Answer (score 2):

"Crafting an email and access the user's gmail tab" = [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) which is unethical.
One way to achieve what you want is to ask your users to make their Gmail handle mailto: links by following this guide -> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10966?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

No such way to set it from inside your applications. But gmail does provide you setting to open mailto links in gmail.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I didn't know this. However, Some of my users may not be savvy enough to tweak gmail settings.

Comment: true, but sadly how everyone wants to send mail is their choice, so its not really a good idea to implement it in code anyway. Also as @Darin has pointed out, different browsers handle mailto differently, so your solution wont be a robust one.